# Remove duplicates in a DF when specified column is different and contains a specific value compared to previous row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the dataframe outlined below and need to remove the second row. Rows removed should only have a Reason of 'RTE' and be directly following a Reason of 100. Therefore row 4 should remain even though row 5 has the same Emp and Salary.

Is there a way to do this with Pandas? I've tried drop_duplicates() and duplicates() but unsure of a way to define a condition where Reason must be RTE and follow a Reason of 100. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thank you!

DF:

| Emp | Reason | Date | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 100 | 01/23/2017 | 10000 |
| 2 | RTE | 02/26/2018 | 10000 |
| 2 | RTE | 05/07/2018 | 101000 |
| 2 | RTE | 05/06/2019 | 102000 |
| 2 | 800 | 01/31/2020 | 102000 |

Desired Result:

| Emp | Reason | Date | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 100 | 01/23/2017 | 10000 |
| 2 | RTE | 05/07/2018 | 101000 |
| 2 | RTE | 05/06/2019 | 102000 |
| 2 | 800 | 01/31/2020 | 102000 |

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Emp", "Reason", "Salary"], keep='first')` - this does not remove row 2
`df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Emp", "Salary"], keep='first')` - this removes row 5 which I want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a mask for records that have RTE and prior row 100, and then use `~` to select only the rows that don't match.

Edit: Changed the input df to have examples of matches w/ and w/o the same salary.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Emp': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 'Reason': ['100', 'RTE', '100', 'RTE', '800'],
 'Date': ['01/23/2017',
  '02/26/2018',
  '05/07/2018',
  '05/06/2019',
  '01/31/2020'],
 'Salary': [10000, 10000, 101000, 102000, 102000]})


m = df['Reason'].eq('RTE') & df['Reason'].shift(1).eq('100') & df['Salary'].eq(df['Salary'].shift(1))
df = df[~m]


print(df)
```

Output

```
   Emp Reason        Date  Salary
0    2    100  01/23/2017   10000
2    2    100  05/07/2018  101000
3    2    RTE  05/06/2019  102000
4    2    800  01/31/2020  102000
```

Comment: Thank you! This is almost perfect. The only issue is that it is removing the RTE record after a 100 record regardless of the Salary column. I only need the RTE row removed if the Salary in the RTE row is equal to the Salary in the 100 row. Does that make sense?

Comment: m = df['Reason'].eq('RTE') & df['Reason'].shift(1).eq('100') & (df['Salary'] > df['Salary'].shift(1))

I tried adding this to the end but it is not making any changes

Comment: Ah, thank you. Makes more sense how .eq() can be used. I appreciate the help!